# Google HtmlService and knockout.js

Tags: javascript, web, knockout.js, google-apps-script

I'am using Google HtmlService to deploy an application on the web. 
I's very simple:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

Also i'm using jQuery and knockout.js
in index.html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript">         </script>
<body>
Insert text here:
<input type="text">
<br>
asdf
<br>
<script>
var viewModel = {
  user_name: "YYK"
}
$(function() {
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);;
});
</script>
</body>
```

but when I open my site in browser it crushes with error

> TypeError: undefined is not a function

and tons of dump. 
When I do the same simple thing on my local host it works fine! 
Is it a problem in Caja sanatization or anything else, and what I have to do to make knockout.js work with this google service?
Thanks!

Comment: Some typos in the code snippet (such as missing close script tag). Fix them first to eliminate them as the problem.

Comment: Insert script tags (jquery, ko) either in head section or at the end of the body section, as i can see currently script tags are neither in head section nor in body section which could be a problem because if jquery is not loaded than `$` is undefined

Comment: Thanks for pointing of error, but it is only in this code quote. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this with the [HelloWorld example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html) and got a couple of errors flagged by chrome. Almost certainly this is Caja at work. Unless you are a guru in both caja and js, I suggest that your way forward is to avoid HtmlService. [My approach](http://davethinkingaloud.blogspot.co.nz/2013/03/jsonp-and-google-apps-script.html) is to host the html (in Google Drive for low throughput applications) and use jsonp and GAS ContentService to interface with your google apps script.

Comment: It's pitty, but I'm not guru in Caja ))